# Issues posting to my mongo database in react native

Tags: mongodb, express, react-native

I am very new to React Native and I am trying to figure out how to connect my front end to my back end. I realize I may have my folder structure set up oddly but the connection works and I can fetch data from the database but when I attempt a post, it throws a 500 error. I cannot seem to figure out what is happening with it. If anyone has some insight I would greatly appreciate it. The post method console logs the req.body and "Here we are" in the controller file but fails immediately after that.

```
// index.js

require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const { UserRoutes, TweetsRoutes } = require("./modules");
import dbConfig from "./config/db";

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(morgan("dev"));
// -----Database ----- \\
dbConfig(process.env.MONGO_DB_URL);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use("/api", [UserRoutes, TweetsRoutes]);

// app.get("/", (req, res) => {
//   res.send("endpoint live");
// });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

```
// db.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
export default mongoURL => {
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
  mongoose.connect(
    mongoURL,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  );

  let db = mongoose.connection;

  db.once("open", () => console.log("Connected to the database"));
  db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "Mongo connection error: "));
};
```

```
// tweetController.js

import Tweet from "./TweetsSchema";

module.exports = {
  createTweet: async (req, res, next) => {
    const createdTweet = req.body;
    console.log("req.body: ", req.body);

    try {
      console.log("Here we are");
      let tweet = await new Tweet.create(createdTweet);
      tweet.save();
      console.log("tweet: ", tweet);
      res.status(201).json(tweet);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: true,
        message: "There was an error creating the tweet"
      });
    }
  },
  getAllTweets: async (req, res, next) => {
    const foundTweets = await Tweet.find({})
      .lean()
      .exec();
    res.status(200).json(foundTweets);
    next();
  }
};
```

```
// actions.js


export const postTweet = tweet => {
  let response = axios
     .post(
       `http://10.0.2.2:<PORT>/api/tweet`,
       { tweet },
       {
         headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
         }
       }
     )
     .then(res => {
       return res.data;
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
     });
  return {
    type: POST_TWEET,
    payload: response
  };
};
```

Comment: 2 Things:
1) Please also post your req.body and  tweetSchema.js - It seems a schema mismatch might cause the operation to fail
2) Might be a good idea to log the original error message in the catch block in addition to "There was an error creating the tweet" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you mixed 2 commands for creating a new document

Instead of using both `new` and `create` like this:

`let tweet = await new Tweet.create(createdTweet);`

You should use only 1 of them like so:

```
let tweet = await Tweet.create(createdTweet);
tweet.save();
```

Or:

```
let tweet = new Tweet(createdTweet);
await tweet.save();
```

Comment: THank you for the response! Between these two which is best practice? Removing the new did not fix the error but it showed a new much more specific error and it looks like it is a schema issue where the authorId is required, but I attempted the post inside postman and it still returns an error but a different one than before. I'll have to keep playing with it!

Comment: Regarding what is better, I'm not sure since mongoose recommend both. One is a static function and the other an instance method. 
Regarding the schema issues please share your schema and the payload you are sending in your request